# Batch file not finding itself once temp files cleared

Tags: windows, batch-file, temp

I am encountering an error that states that it can not find the running batch file once it cleared the temp files.

This only happened when I compiled this into an exe file.

I think this is caused by the fact that the exe created a temporary batch file in the temp folder. After that, the batch file itself is asked to clear the temp folder, thus clearing its own alter ego. How do I get around this?

P.S. this is my code snippet that is causing the problem:

```
cls
del /s /f /q c:\windows\temp\*.*
rd /s /q c:\windows\temp
md c:\windows\temp
del /s /f /q C:\WINDOWS\Prefetch
del /s /f /q %temp%\*.*
rd /s /q %temp%
md %temp%
rd /s /q c:\windows\tempor~1
rd /s /q c:\windows\temp
rd /s /q c:\windows\tmp
rd /s /q c:\windows\ff*.tmp
rd /s /q c:\windows\history
rd /s /q c:\windows\cookies
rd /s /q c:\windows\recent
rd /s /q c:\windows\spool\printers
del c:\WIN386.SWP
echo.
echo.
```

Comment: IMO you are better off letting windows tools do this task. Take a look at cleanmgr.exe eventually with sageset / sagerun

Comment: Batch-to-Exe converters usually simply pack the batch file into an archive which is extracted into the temporary directory when executing; if you find out how that temporary path is called, you could exclude it from deletion. Anyway, why do you have to convert it to an Exe after all?